# MySQL stored procedures - "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

MySQL 5.6

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
DECLARE _idKeep INT;
SET _idKeep = 1;
PREPARE string FROM "UPDATE users set firstname='Joe' where id=?";
EXECUTE string USING _idKeep;
/*SELECT _idKeep;*/
END
```

Error Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '_idKeep;

If I comment out the PREPARE and EXECUTE statement, and uncomment the SELECT statement, then the error message goes away.  Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use local variable in your query, user defined variable only.

> Parameter values can be supplied only by user variables, and the USING clause must name exactly as many variables as the number of parameter markers in the statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execute.html

> User-defined variables are session-specific. A user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. (Exception: A user with access to the Performance Schema user_variables_by_thread table can see all user variables for all sessions.) All variables for a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

> Because local variables are in scope only during stored program execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements created within a stored program. Prepared statement scope is the current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no longer be in scope. For example, SELECT ... INTO local_var cannot be used as a prepared statement. This restriction also applies to stored procedure and function parameters.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html

> A prepared statement created within a stored program continues to exist after the program finishes executing and can be executed outside the program later.
>
> A statement prepared in stored program context cannot refer to stored procedure or function parameters or local variables because they go out of scope when the program ends and would be unavailable were the statement to be executed later outside the program. As a workaround, refer instead to user-defined variables, which also have session scope.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html

You could use user-defined variable and restrict edition of it anywhere but this function.